# Nuxt : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

As a side project (and as a way to get better at coding), I'm trying to develop a website using Nuxt3. In the future I'm going to use a database but for now, I'm juste using a json file with all the manuscripts info.

When I click on a card and the navigateTo function gets called, I have en error <TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')> which leads me to my manuscriptInfos.vue.

-It goes index.vue -> [detail]-[id].vue

-[detail]-[id].vue is composed of manuscriptScan.vue (which works fine) and infoContainer.vue (<- the problem child).

-infoContainer has manuscriptInfo.vue (the culprit) and transcriptionContainer.vue

Index.vue has access to the title and the query changes accordingly to what it's supposed to show so I don't really see what I forgot. Could you help me with that ?

index.vue :

```js
<template>
  <div class="index-container">
    <nav-side-bar/>
    <div class="body">
      <div class="ms-cards-container">
      <manuscript-card v-for="manuscript in manuscripts" :key="manuscript.id" :manuscript="manuscript"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {useManuscripts} from "~/composables/useManuscripts";

useHead({
  title: "Palimpseste",
})

const {manuscripts} = useManuscripts();
</script>
```

manuscriptCard.vue:

```js
<template>
    <div class="ms-card" @click="navigateTo(`${manuscript.title}-${manuscript.id}`)">
      <img :src="manuscript.img" alt="miniature du manuscrit">
      <div class="card-detail-container">
        <p>{{ manuscript.title }}</p>
        <div class="card-secundary-detail">
          <p>{{ manuscript.year }}</p>
          <p>{{ manuscript.pageNumber }}p</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps({
  manuscript: Object
})
</script>
```

[detail]-[id].vue :

```js
<template>
  <div class="container" v-if="manuscript">
    <detail-manuscript-scan :manuscript="manuscript"/>
    <detail-info-container :manuscript="manuscript"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {useManuscripts} from "~/composables/useManuscripts";

const route = useRoute();
const {manuscripts} = useManuscripts();
const manuscript = computed(() => {
  return manuscripts.find((m) => {
    return m.id === parseInt(route.params.id);
  })
})

useHead({
  title : route.params.title as string,
});
</script>
```

infoContainer.vue :

```js
<template>
  <div class="details-container">
    <detail-manuscript-infos :manuscript="manuscript"/>
    <detail-transcription-container :manuscript="manuscript"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

manscriptInfos.vue :

```js
<template>
  <div class="ms-infos">
    <h1>{{ manuscript.title }}</h1>
    <p>par {{ manuscript.author }}</p>
    <p>{{ manuscript.presentation }}</p>
    <p>Soumis par [Untel]</p>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({
  manuscript: Object
})
</script>
```

All help will be very much appreciated !
Thank you very much !